# Spring Webflux: optional RequestPart/RequestParam is still required?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to use optional request parameters / request parts, but when I don't provide an optional parameter, my request just hangs indenfinitely.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service")
class MyController {
    @PostMapping
    fun print(@RequestPart("name", required = false) name: String) {
        if (name != null)
            print(name)
        else
            print("grr")
    }
}
```

If I provide the parameter `name` in my request, it no longer hangs definitely in postman, the request goes through. But I expected it to go through anyway when I don't provide the parameter `name` and print "grr".

This required property not working properly (at least in my mind) is validated when you add another supposedly optional property.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service")
class MyController {
    @PostMapping
    fun print(@RequestPart("name", required = false) name: String,
              @RequestPart("friend_name", required = false) friendsName: String) {
        if (name != null)
            print(name)
        else
            print("grr")
    }
}
```

Now when I provide the parameter `name` but not `friend_name`, it says the value cannot be null.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-10-10T09:50:49.305+0000",
    "path": "/service",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Parameter specified as non-null is null: method co.example.controllers.MyController.print, parameter friendsName"
}
```

I have tried the same for `@RequestParam` and `@RequestPart` with the same results.

Comment: so using the nullable operator `?` actually fixed the issue haha. If you want to post the answer, I'll mark it as accepted :) -> It's using `@RequestPart` because my actual code is for `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark your optional parameters as nullable. Therefore:

```
@RequestPart("name", required = false) name: String?
@RequestPart("friend_name", required = false) friendsName: String?
```